# How can I grow the stack panel with a different color in XAML for an input field?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a `TextBox` and a `StackPanel` underneath, which together should result in an input field. That's why I want that as soon as you click into the text box, the `StackPanel` underneath changes the color with an effect that the new color has, so to speak, a growing effect, as well as the material design nugget in the HintAssist.

So as an example of this:

[image: Picture1]

To this:

[image: Picture2]

But without a NuGet package only with XAML code. This is my code now but I have no idea how to make this.

```
<Grid>
  <DockPanel>
    <StackPanel StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="#2D2D30"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="78">
      <DockPanel Margin="0,15" >
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Width="152" 
                    Margin="0 0 600 0" Height="1" Background="Black"> 
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox Foreground="LightBlue" Text="Eingabe" Width="170" Margin="20 0 0 0"
                             FontSize="20" Background="#2D2D30" BorderThickness="0" Height="30">
        </TextBox>
      </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
  </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a `StackPanel` here, a `Rectangle` should be enough to display the line. You can assign a name to your `TextBox`. Add a style to your `Rectangle` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to the `TextBox` using its name and checks the `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` property to determine if the focus is in the `TextBox`. If you still want to use the `StackPanel`, you can adapt it easily.

```
<DockPanel Margin="0,15">
   <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
              Width="152"
              Margin="0 0 600 0"
              Height="1">
      <Rectangle.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, ElementName=MyTextBox}" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"/>
               </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </Rectangle.Style>
   </Rectangle>
   <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox"
            Foreground="LightBlue"
            Text="Eingabe"
            Width="170"
            Margin="20 0 0 0"
            FontSize="20"
            Background="#2D2D30"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Height="30">
   </TextBox>
</DockPanel>
```